# Change in one-way bound directive attribute during test not updating directive scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, directive

I'm currently attempting to test an angular directive using jasmine.

Here is a simplified example of what the directive under test looks like:

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('testDirective', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict:'A',
      scope: {
        myAttr: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html(scope.myAttr);

        scope.$watch('myAttr', function(n, o) {
          if(n !== o) {
            element.html(n);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Using an isolate scope, it is one-way binding the value of the attribute data-my-attr to the scope value of myAttr and then watching the value of myAttr for any change, at which time it updates the displayed element.

Once again, this code has been heavily modified for clarity, so forgive the highly contrived example.

The test is compiling an element containing this directive, verifying that the initial html of the element is set correctly (it is) and then changing the value of the attribute and expecting the corresponding change in the element to occur (it is not). This is a simplified version of the test code.

```
it('fires myAttr watch', function() {
    var body = angular.element('body');
    var template = angular.element('<div id="testid" data-test-directive data-my-attr="initialValue"/>');

    body.append([template]);
    compile(template)(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    expect(angular.element('#testid').text()).toEqual('initialValue');

    template.attr('data-my-attr', 'newValue');

    scope.$digest();

    expect(angular.element('#testid').text()).toEqual('newValue');
  });
```

Although this directive works as expected when used in production, under test it seems that updating the value of the attribute doesn't cause the corresponding scope value to update, which results in the watch never firing. Why doesn't the value on the scope get updated, and why does this only happen in tests?

Here is a plunkr demonstrating the problem http://plnkr.co/edit/MmS1X2zrPZyGSUIVUsDg?p=preview

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add `compile(template)(scope);` after you update the value before calling scope digest

Comment: I noticed that doing so does solve the problem, but I guess I'm uncertain whether it is the correct solution or a hack that happens to work. I assumed that $compile was a one time deal intended to identify directives and bind them appropriately to the  scope, does that mean that behind the scenes whenever I reach into the html and change something angular is recompiling everything? Furthermore if that is the case, what is triggering the recompile in the production code (where this works correctly) that isn't happening in the test?

Comment: Your test is wrong in that case. In your test you are modifying attribute of element, which is not going to get evaluated by digest. You need to recompile. And yes even in the application if you change something manually in your html via manual DOM operation (eg:- binding a model, changing directive, adding directive on the fly on an element) you need to recompile it. And well how are you doing it in your production code..

Comment: Are you doing it this way in your production code? http://plnkr.co/edit/BwDtXZRMtMWAcvMSL8vZ?p=preview You need to post your actual code as well..

Comment: Ah good catch, you are correct. I failed to notice that the actual usage of the directive was binding it to a scope variable (as your plunkr suggests) which explains why a simple digest loop would be enough to update the value. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile the element after updating the attribute of the element with new text. and in your case you don't need `scope.digest` at all (since you are not really binding the text with `{{modelvalue}}`). Reason is you are not attaching a bound variable instead you are assigning a plan text to the attribute, so you need to recompile the element.

So you just need to do:-

```
template.attr('data-my-attr', 'newValue');
compile(template)(scope);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hr8IH0SS4b64qzBspaOD?p=preview)**

Had your test been like this (using angular binding when directive is used):-

```
var body = angular.element('body');
rootScope.initialValue ="initialValue";
var template = angular.element('<div id="testid" data-test-directive data-my-attr="{{initialValue}}"/>');

body.append([template]);
compile(template)(scope);
scope.$digest();
expect(angular.element('#testid').text()).toEqual('initialValue');

rootScope.initialValue = "newValue";
scope.$digest();

expect(angular.element('#testid').text()).toEqual('newValue');
```

It would work by invoking $digest.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BwDtXZRMtMWAcvMSL8vZ?p=preview)**